# Why strtok modifying stl container

Tags: c++, stl

In the below code, i am expecting output to be abc#def. But i am getting output as abcdef. It seems strtok is modifying the vector even though i am not directly passing vector to the strtok function. May i know how it is happening inside

```
std::vector<std::pair<const std::string, int>> x;

std::vector<std::string> z;

int main()
{

    char* pch;
    x.push_back(std::make_pair("abc#def", 1));

    std::string m = x[0].first;

    pch = strtok ((char*)(m.c_str()),"#");

    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        z.push_back(pch);
        pch =strtok (NULL, "#");
    }

    cout<<x[0].first<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're modifying std::string buffer because strtok modifies its parameter (it's the way it works).

Comment: what should i do to get abc#def in output using strtok

Comment: `strtok` modifies the parsed string. That's the way `strtok` works. Casting a like this `((char*)(m.c_str())` is definitly a bad idea.

Comment: Do not use `strtok`. Especially not in c++.

Answer (score 0):

Copied instances of `std::string` may use the same backing buffer. That is x[0] and m may actually use the same backing buffer.

This is why the `c_str()` member returns `const char *` - you are not allowed to modify it.

You are casting away the const by using the C-style cast (char *).

In general, better use C++ casts: static_cast<>/reinterpret_cast<>/dynamic_cast<> and const_cast<> if you really need to strip the const. The latter is only intended to interface old C-code without const qualifiers. You shall not require to use it within normal C++ code.

Comment: Actually, to be pedantic, they are no longer allowed to use the same backing buffer, but some libraries still do anyway.

Comment: Also, the advice to use `reinterpret_cast<>` here instead is silly, because that won't fix anything.

Comment: @MooingDuck (1): That's the only explanation for the behavior he sees here, although it might not be allowed anymore. (2) That's why I said "in general".

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation, `c_str()` must be returning a reference to the internal `char` buffer of the string, without making any copy. From the manpage of glibc `strtok`:

> ## BUGS
>
> Be cautious when using these functions.  If you do use them, note that:
>
> - These functions modify their first argument.

so, yes, `strtok` applied to the pointer returned from `c_str()` will modify the string buffer.

You should be using `std::getline` instead of `strtok` to split string at `#`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<const std::string, int>> x;

int main() {
    x.push_back(std::make_pair("abc#def", 1));

    std::string m = x[0].first;
    std::string token;

    while(std::getline(m, token, '#')) {
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
    }

    cout<< x[0].first <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

or, if you *really* need to use `strtok`, at least duplicate the buffer returned by `c_str()` with `strdup` (and remember to `free()` it).

Comment: Actually, there is no guarantee (or wasn't before C++11) that `c_str()` will return a pointer to the internal representation (although I've never heard of an implementation where it didn't).  And modifying anything through the pointer returned by `c_str()` is undefined behavior; on some implementations, it can have _very_ strange results.

Comment: And I wouldn't use `getline` for this.  What's wrong with `std::find` or `std::string::find`?

Comment: @JamesKanze `std::getline` is handy if the string contains more than one `#` separator. It's certainly possible to iterate over tokens using `std::find`, but I find it quite cumbersome. About  `c_str`, I edited the answer expliciting the "your implementation has this behaviour" part.

Comment: There's nothing cumbersome about `std::find` or `std::string::find`, and they easily expand to using one of a set of separators, and if you replace `std::find` with `std::find_if`, you can define just about any criteria as your separator (any white space, for example).  And of course, the name isn't misleading either; using `getline` for anything but reading lines is misleading to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using of `strtok` use `find_first_of` & `find_first_not_of` methods of `string`

like this:

```
using namespace std;
int main () {
    string s="abc#def";
    string temp = s,res;
    while(temp.size()){
        size_t st,en;
        st = temp.find_first_not_of("#");
        en = temp.find_first_of("#",st);

        res= temp.substr(st,en);
        cout<<res.c_str()<<endl;
        temp=(en == string::npos) ? "" : temp.substr(en);
    }
  return 0;
}
```